# Using Ruby collect with more than 1 variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sure this is a simple one, but is it possible to return more than 1 attribute with collect

So I can do

```
User.all.collect { |user| user.firstname}
```

but I can't do

```
User.all.collect { |user| user.firstname, user.lastname}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `User.all.collect &:firstname`, `User.all.collect { |user| [user.firstname, user.lastname] }`

Comment: Depending on your needs, [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) is another possibility: `["b c", "d e"].flat_map(&:split) => ["b", "c", "d", "e"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`collect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Array.html#method-i-collect) returns an array.

You can make it an array of pairs:

```
User.all.collect { |user| [user.firstname, user.lastname]}
```

With ActiveRecord [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck), you can have the same result with a more efficient request:

```
User.pluck(:firstname, :lastname)
```

You can also `collect` "firstname, lastname":

```
User.all.collect { |user| "#{user.firstname}, #{user.lastname}"}
```